# My contact form worked fine, until I added attachment option. Messages no longer get sent. Any idea how I could validate the attachment field?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have made a contact form with the following fields: Name, Email, Message. It all worked fine - messages were sent to my email - until I added the attachments option to the form.

I've tried validating the attachment fields by searching up tutorials, but nothing seems to work. I guess I'm just not sure how to implement it to my already existing code.. Any help here?

**Here is the form:**

```
<?php include 'contact-form.php'; ?>

<form id="contact" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Nimi" type="text" tabindex="1" name="thename"  value="<?= $thename ?>" autofocus>
    <div class="error"><span><?= $name_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Email" type="text" tabindex="2" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>">
    <div class="error"><span><?= $email_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <textarea placeholder="Sisesta sõnum siia.." type="text" tabindex="3" name="message"></textarea>
    <div class="error"><span><?= $message_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="attachment1">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment1" name="attachment[]" size="35">
    <label for="attachment2">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment2" name="attachment[]" size="35">
    <div class="error"><span><?= $attachment_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Saatmine">Saada</button>
</fieldset>
<div class="success"><?= $success; ?></div>
<div class="error"><?= $error; ?></div>
</form>
```

**Here is PHP validation code *contact-form.php*:**

```
<?php
$name_error = $email_error = $message_error = $attachment_error = "";
$thename = $email = $message = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["thename"])) {
    $name_error = "Palun sisesta nimi";
} else {
    $thename = test_input($_POST["thename"]);
    // check if name only contains letters, whitespace and hyphen
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]*$/",$thename)) {
        $name_error = "Sisestada saab ainult tähti, tühikuid ja sidekriipse";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $email_error = "Palun sisesta email";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // email validation
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_error = "Sisesta email korrektselt";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Palun sisesta sõnum";
} else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}

if (empty($_FILES["attachment"])) {
    $attachment_error = "Palun sisesta enda eluloo fail";
}

if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' ){
    $message_body = '';
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
    }


    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Eesti Elulood';
    $message = "Sulle saadeti kiri Rannu koguduse kodulehelt.\n\nSaatja nimi: $thename\n\nSaatja email: $email\n\nSõnum: $message";
    // create email headers
    $headers =  'From: '.$email."\r\n".
                'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {
$semi_rand = md5(uniqid(time()));
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers = "From: " . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($thename) . '?=' . " 
<$email>" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($thename) . '?=' . 
" <$email>" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Return-Path: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= " Boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$datamsg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format." . PHP_EOL . 
PHP_EOL;
$datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}" . PHP_EOL;
$datamsg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=\"UTF-8\"" . PHP_EOL;
$datamsg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$datamsg .= $message . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $index++) 
{
if ($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$index] != "") {
  $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$index];
  $data_file = 
chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment'] 
['tmp_name'][$index])));
  $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name=\" 
{$file_name}\"" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=\"{$file_name}\"" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 
$data_file . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
}
$datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
}

    if (@mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', 
$datamsg, $headers, "-f$email")){
        $success = "Thankyou, message sent!.";
    } else {
        $error = "Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please try again!";
    }   
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
```

After hitting the submit button, It just takes me to the index.php page..
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are using the mail php in the wrong manner... use: `if (mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', $datamsg, $headers, "-f$email")) {` since `$datamsg` already includes your `$message`, use the 5th parameter at the end `"-f$email"` that force the sending...

Comment: Use the constant `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` this will allow the server to adjust the code as used in the O/S hosting of the server...

Comment: Did you read this? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

Comment: Did you read my full answer? `action="<?= $SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` is wrong as you can read at point 5) and 6) of my answer.

Comment: I suggest this approach... example: `if (empty($_POST["thename"])) {
  $error = "Palun sisesta nimi";
  include("form.php");
  exit();
}`. Repeat for each field `$email`, `$message`... etc...and in `form.php` you only need `<div class="error"><span><?php echo $error; ?></span></div>`.

Comment: Adding `if (mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', $datamsg, $headers, "-f$email")) {` gives me HTTP ERROR 500 :/ 
And about PHP_EOL, I am not sure where and how to use it..
I did read your answer and changed action to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

Comment: What version are you using of PHP? Seems very old version, I suggest you PHP 7.2 or better... write a file named "info.php" and put inside it <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Execute it and then report the version you are using...

Comment: With `unset($_POST['submit']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
    }` what do you want obtain? and... with: `$message = "My message.\n\nSaatja nimi: $thename\n\nSaatja email: 
$email\n\nSõnum: $message";` what you expect does this code?

Comment: I am using PHP version 7.3.6. 
And to be honest, I don't remember what was `unset($_POST['submit']); foreach...` for.. And `$message = "My message.\n\nSaatja nimi: $thename\n\nSaatja email: $email\n\nSõnum: $message";` is how I receive the email.

Comment: Sir, I updated my question with current code. If by any chance you have time to see if you find a mistake there.. Right now, after hitting Submit, I get brought to index.php page and nothing happens..

Comment: remove `$data = trim($data);`

Comment: There are so many things you could do in your code that they don't work and that produce unexpected behaviors... read all my comments, please.

Comment: Ahhh, It finally works. I tried removing 'echo' from the action, since u suggested either `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` and `<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`
After removing `echo`, files get sent perfectly. **Thankyou !!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have no mail attachments code into your php code except for the html markup, so you cannot send your mail attachments.

2) You have to encode the attachments using `chunk_split(base64_encode())` and then you have to import them into your message part using the correct way.

3) You forgot to enter the correct headers, that's the other reason why you can't send your mails.

4) You have to consider that if you use GMail there may be a limit to the type of file you can send and so read this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

5) I suggest you to use the long php tag instead the short tag:

Instead of writing `<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`, write `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

6) You have a serious error into your php and this is the reason why pressing submit you are in the home instead of your contact form:

`<?= $SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` is wrong!

`<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` is correct!

See you point 5)

Here is an example of correct html markup for attachments:

```
<label for="attachment1">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment1" name="attachment[]" size="35">
<label for="attachment2">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment2" name="attachment[]" size="35">
<label for="attachment3">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment3" name="attachment[]" size="35">
```

Here is an example of correct php mail code for attachments:

```
if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {
  $semi_rand = md5(uniqid(time()));
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
  $headers = "From: " . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($sender_name) . '?=' . " <$from_email>" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($sender_name) . '?=' . " <$from_email>" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_email" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= " Boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
  $datamsg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=\"UTF-8\"" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= $message . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $index++) {
    if ($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$index] != "") {
      $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$index];
      $data_file = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$index])));
      $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}" . PHP_EOL;
      $datamsg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name=\"{$file_name}\"" . PHP_EOL;
      $datamsg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=\"{$file_name}\"" . PHP_EOL;
      $datamsg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $data_file . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
  $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
}
if (@mail($recipient_email, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', $datamsg, $headers, "-f$from_email")) {
  exit("Files Sent Successfully");
} else {
  exit("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
}
```

Where `$sender_name` is the name of sender, `$from_email` is the email of sender, `$recipient_email` is the recipient of your email.

You can take an example from my code and integrate it into your project, I wrote only the essential parts concerning the sending of attachments.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried changing my code, but I am still not receiving the mail. After hitting the submit button it just brings me to my websites index page. 
I changed the HTML markup as you showed above and I edited my question so you can see my php code with changes at the bottom of my question. 
I feel so stupid..